# Cannot call value of non-function type 'GIDSignIn'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement google sign in into my app. But the problem is when i add this line of code to my App.swift file i'm getting an error. I tried to remove the `()` from the `sharedInstance` but if i do this i'm getting another error (`Value of type 'GIDSignIn' has no member 'clientID'`). I'm beginner on swift and swiftUI

**The error:**

```
Cannot call value of non-function type 'GIDSignIn'
```

**Line of code:**

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
```

**My App.swift File:**

```
//
//  iGrow_GoalsApp.swift
//  iGrow Goals
//
//  Created by George Sepetadelis on 3/8/21.
//

import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import GoogleSignIn
import UserNotifications


@main
struct iGrow_GoalsApp: App {
    
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            let viewModel = AppViewModel()
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(viewModel)
        }
    }
    
}

extension iGrow_GoalsApp {
    
    func setUpAthetication() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    
}

class AppDelegate : NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    var window: UIWindow?
    
    func application(
        _ app: UIApplication,
        open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]
    ) -> Bool {
        var handled: Bool
        
        handled = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.handle(url)
        if handled {
            return true
        }
        
        // Handle other custom URL types.
        
        // If not handled by this app, return false.
        return false
    }
    
    
    func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
        
        return true
    }
    
    
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.self.window = window
        
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issues. did you mange to solve the problem? Thanks

Comment: Count me on this issue as well. I have seen multiple examples where this is referenced for SwiftUI, but none of them work.

Comment: Same issue at my side also. it working fine before i run the 'pod update' command. Now its showing the error message Cannot call value of non-function type 'GIDSignIn'.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue until I used this version of GoogleSignIn

```
pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 4.4.0'
```

Comment: for me what worked was the version '~> 5.0.0' which ended installing 5.0.2 just in case someone find this helpful